# jquery get window scroll position after clicking on internal link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get scroll position after I click on anchor (internal click).

```
$(".nav-link").click(function(){
        console.log($(window).scrollTop());
});
```

But the value is the one of the position before the scroll is done. How can I get the value when the event is completed?

Comment: You can watch the [window onscroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll) event or use hyperlink hashes (i.e. `<a href="#someId">`) and listen for the [onhashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange) event. Checking scroll position after those events should give you an accurate result.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onhashchange = function () {
        console.log($(window).scrollTop());
};
```